# How can I build a plot data in Excel without separating categories into multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

How can I plot the following data where each category is colored differently in excel?

```
category | datetime            | score
--------------------------------------
foo      | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 1
bar      | 2016-01-01 00:00:01 | 2
bar      | 2016-01-01 00:00:02 | 3
foo      | 2016-01-01 00:00:02 | 2
baz      | 2016-01-01 00:00:02 | 5
foo      | 2016-01-01 00:00:03 | 5
baz      | 2016-01-01 00:00:03 | 8
qux      | 2016-01-01 00:00:03 | 1
foo      | 2016-01-01 00:00:04 | 3
bar      | 2016-01-01 00:00:04 | 3
baz      | 2016-01-01 00:00:04 | 6
qux      | 2016-01-01 00:00:04 | 1
```

Is it possible without first converting the above into something like the this?

```
datetime            | foo | bar | baz | qux
-------------------------------------------
2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 1   |     |     |  
2016-01-01 00:00:01 |     | 2   |     |  
2016-01-01 00:00:02 | 2   | 3   | 5   |  
2016-01-01 00:00:03 | 5   |     | 8   | 1
2016-01-01 00:00:04 | 3   | 3   | 6   | 1
```

If it is not possible, can you suggest a quick way to pivot the data into the category columns?

Comment: This is easy with a *VBA* macro.  Is this approach acceptable ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, depends. I'm on a Mac, using Excel 2016 v.15.17. Typically Mac Excel is crippled for VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really easy to do with a pivot table. Set it up with Datetime as your Row Label, Category as your column Label, and Sum of Score as your value.

Pivot Fields:

[image]

Resulting Pivot Table:

[image]